# Fail2ban regex working but not banning. DNS warning instead

Tags: regex, logging, fail2ban

So, I've been reading issues for some days and don't seem to find a solution anywhere.
I'm making some tests on a web server lab, I have set up two VMs (Ubuntu 20.04) server and client.
On the server I have a PHP login app configured to give me this log whenever someone fails to log in.

```
root@local:/var/log/apache2# tail -f error.log
[Fri Jun 18 10:13:37.657446 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 2465] [client 192.168.1.11:44750] [error] failed login, referer: http://192.168.1.10/index.php
[Fri Jun 18 10:13:41.434454 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 2465] [client 192.168.1.11:44750] [error] failed login, referer: http://192.168.1.10/index.php
[Fri Jun 18 10:13:46.236750 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 2465] [client 192.168.1.11:44750] [error] failed login, referer: http://192.168.1.10/index.php
```

And Fail2Ban v0.11.1 configured to catch it.
/etc/fail2ban/jail.local:

```
[login-ban]
enabled   = true
port      = http,https
filter    = login-ban
logpath  = /var/log/apache2/error.log
maxretry = 3
findtime  = 180
bantime = 60
```

/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/login-ban.conf:

```
[Definition]
failregex =  ^\[.*\]\s\[.*]\s\[.*].*\[client.*<HOST>\].*\[error\].*
ignoreregex =
```

Now, the regex works perfectly, if I check with fail2ban-regex:

```
fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/error.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/login-ban.conf --print-all-matched
```

I get

```
|- Matched line(s):
|  [Fri Jun 18 10:36:07.312503 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 780] [client 192.168.1.11:44754] [error] failed login, referer: http://192.168.1.10/index.php
|  [Fri Jun 18 10:36:14.417955 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 784] [client 192.168.1.11:44756] [error] failed login, referer: http://192.168.1.10/index.php
```

But fail2ban is not banning the IP and the fail2ban.log is throwing me a DNS warning:

```
2021-06-18 10:50:22,083 fail2ban.ipdns          [2154]: WARNING Determined IP using DNS Lookup: 8 = {'0.0.0.8'}
2021-06-18 10:50:22,085 fail2ban.filter         [2154]: INFO    [login-ban] Found 0.0.0.8 - 2021-06-18 10:50:22
```

I've tried setting the usedns parameter to 'no' and to 'raw' the only thing that accomplished was getting rid of the dns warning log, still no banning and not recording the host that was trying to login.

I hope this is enough info, and that this will help someone out there as much as me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OFFTOPIC:** *please move this question to serverfault or other better suitable site for that (this is offtopic for SO)*

as for your issue, just stop to use catch-alls (`.*` etc),
e. g. one correction to make it work could be:

```
- ... \[client.*<HOST>\] ...
+ ... \[client <HOST>:\d+\] ...
```

RE `.*` is greedy, so it matches as many chars as possible, and `<HOST>` can match anything (hostname), not the address only, and better use `<ADDR>` instead, if your fail2ban version >= 0.10.

And your whole expression is "vulnerable" due to several catch-alls (so the anchor does not really taken).

Comment: Oh man, so sorry for the misplacement... I'm new to these communities. Thanks a lot anyways your solution worked and now the service is banning as it should. I will proceed to move the question to serverfault. BTW I did the change you suggested plus replaced everything before \[client with just one \[.* and it worked perfectly, again thank you so much.